# Select options disappear on mouseover in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, mootools, drop-down-menu, joomla1.7

I'm working on a Joomla 1.7 site and I'm having a strange problem in IE8. When trying to select an option from a select box, the options appear for a second and then when you try to select one they disappear. It only happens on a specific page - I've disabled every other module on the page to count out any conflicts (thought for sure it was a conflict with the slideshow, but no luck). If anybody can shed some light on this I'd really appreciate it! Below are some examples - click on the 'Quicksearch' select dropdowns.

This page works fine:
//link removed - solution below

This page doesn't:
//link removed - solution below

Thanks!

> **Solution** -- Thank you both for your input. I figured it out after pulling my hair out for a couple hours! The template was calling IE specific css behavior 'behavior: url(/css/PIE.htc);' for the module wrapper divs. I just forced the select box styles in the template html IE8 specific css and it works now. Nothing like a waste of time with IE! Thanks again.

Comment: Those options worked fine for me in IE8

Comment: @emphaticsunshine - thanks for taking a look. Did the quicksearch drop downs work on both the search page and the home page?

Comment: It worked for me in both pages.

Comment: @emphaticsunshine - thanks for your help. Possibly an IE8 version issue? I'm using IE8 version 8.0.7601.17514 and the drop down won't work on the home page no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some outer div has a MouseOut event. Please [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032714/i-am-going-crazy-select-box-inside-a-dropdown-menu-div-makes-my-dropdown-menu-d) and maybe you will find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
position:relative;
z-index: 0;
```